# Array is repeating same item Issue

Tags: arrays, react-native

Anyone can give me any suggestions ? I am trying to add an item in every 2 content. I couldn't see anything wrong with the code but why is the MyAds number repeating in all my ads entries ? it is supposed to start from MyAds0 and adding on.

```
 MyAds2 
 Content1 
 Content2 
 MyAds2 
 Content3 
 Content4 
 MyAds2 
 Content5
```

Here is my code

```
const dummyData = [
  {
    name: 'Content1',
    subtitle: 'Content1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content2',
    subtitle: 'Content2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content3',
    subtitle: 'Content3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content4',
    subtitle: 'Content4'
  },  
  {
    name: 'Content5',
    subtitle: 'Content5'
  }, 
]

let TheData = InsertContent();

function InsertContent () {
   let thisdata = [];
   let adscounter = 0;
   let tmpData = [ {name:'tmp', subtitle:'tmp'}];
   for (let i=0; i < dummyData.length; i++){
      if (Number.isInteger(i/2)) {
         tmpData[0].name = 'MyAds' + adscounter;
         tmpData[0].subtitle = 'My MyAds Sub' + adscounter;
         thisdata = [...thisdata, tmpData[0]];
         adscounter = adscounter + 1;
      }
      thisdata = [...thisdata, dummyData[i]];
   }
   return thisdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Problem is not with the logic but with the way you are using object and array with spread operator. You really don't have to use a object at first index in a array Instead you can directly use the object with spread operator to store into the array. I just modified your code to make it work as per your requirements.

```js
const dummyData = [
  {
    name: 'Content1',
    subtitle: 'Content1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content2',
    subtitle: 'Content2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content3',
    subtitle: 'Content3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Content4',
    subtitle: 'Content4'
  },  
  {
    name: 'Content5',
    subtitle: 'Content5'
  }, 
];
let TheData = InsertContent();
console.log(TheData);
function InsertContent () {
   let thisdata = [];
   let adscounter = 0;
   let tmpData =  {name:'', subtitle:''};
   for (let i=0; i < dummyData.length; i++){
      if (Number.isInteger(i/2)) {
            tmpData = {
              
             name: 'MyAds' + adscounter,
             subtitle : 'My MyAds Sub' + adscounter
           };
         thisdata = [...thisdata, tmpData];
         adscounter = adscounter + 1;
      }
      thisdata = [...thisdata, dummyData[i]];
   }
   return thisdata;
}
```